# How to skip a step for Argo workflow

Tags: kubernetes, argoproj, argo-workflows

I'm trying out Argo workflow and would like to understand how to freeze a step. Let's say that I have 3 step workflow and a workflow failed at step 2. So I'd like to resubmit the workflow from step 2 using successful step 1's artifact. How can I achieve this? I couldn't find the guidance anywhere on the document.

Answer (score 4):

I think you should consider using [Conditions](https://argoproj.github.io/docs/argo/examples/README.html#conditionals) and [Artifact passing](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-workflows/blob/master/examples/artifact-passing.yaml) in your steps.

> Conditionals provide a way to affect the control flow of a
> workflow at runtime, depending on parameters. In this example
> the 'print-hello' template may or may not be executed depending
> on the input parameter, 'should-print'. When submitted with

> `$ argo submit examples/conditionals.yaml`

> the step will be skipped since 'should-print' will evaluate false.
> When submitted with:

> `$ argo submit examples/conditionals.yaml -p should-print=true`

> the step will be executed since 'should-print' will evaluate true.

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Workflow
metadata:
  generateName: conditional-
spec:
  entrypoint: conditional-example
  arguments:
    parameters:
    - name: should-print
      value: "false"

  templates:
  - name: conditional-example
    inputs:
      parameters:
      - name: should-print
    steps:
    - - name: print-hello
        template: whalesay
        when: "{{inputs.parameters.should-print}} == true"

  - name: whalesay
    container:
      image: docker/whalesay:latest
      command: [sh, -c]
      args: ["cowsay hello"]
```

If you use conditions in each step you will be able to start from a step you like with appropriate condition.

Also have a loot at this article [Argo: Workflow Engine for Kubernetes](https://itnext.io/argo-workflow-engine-for-kubernetes-7ae81eda1cc5) as author explains the use of conditions on [coinflip example](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/argoproj/argo-workflows/master/examples/coinflip.yaml).
You can see many examples on their [GitHub page](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-workflows/tree/master/examples).

Comment: Thanks for the comment :) I know conditionals but would it be possible to use artifacts created from a different run (such as artifact from a previously failed one)?

Comment: You mean using a failed workflow artifact inside new workflow?

Comment: It'd like to take the failed workflow and use a different image to restart from the specific step that failed. So that I don't have to run previous steps that were successful over and over again.

Comment: I don't know, but I don't think this should be possible. The workflow failed and it should not be possible to use artifacts from that workflow in a new workflow especially when the image changes.